# Odoo: Adding Stripe with Payment Acquirer

Tags: javascript, python, html, stripe-payments, odoo

I am trying to integrate Stripe with Odoo. I would like to use stripe.js so my server does not have to store credit card numbers.

To try to figure out how I can do this, I looked at the open source [`payment_paypal`](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/tree/8.0/addons/payment_paypal) add-on. What I found was this:

```
def _get_paypal_urls(self, cr, uid, environment, context=None):
        """ Paypal URLS """
        if environment == 'prod':
            return {
                'paypal_form_url': 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr',
                'paypal_rest_url': 'https://api.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token',
            }
        else:
            return {
                'paypal_form_url': 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr',
                'paypal_rest_url': 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token',
            }
```

where the `'paypal_form_url'` key has the URL that is included inside the `action` attribute of the `<form>` tag on the checkout page.

The way stripe.js is supposed to be included on a webpage is actually like so (from [Stripe's documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-simple)):

```
<form action="/charge" method="POST">
  <script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="pk_test_6pRNASCoBOKtIshFeQd4XMUh"
    data-image="/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
    data-name="Stripe.com"
    data-description="2 widgets"
    data-amount="2000">
  </script>
</form>
```

which obviously has arbitrary JavaScript in the middle of the `form` tag, so that simply setting the `action` attribute will not be enough to make it work. This is a problem because Odoo's template system already fills in the HTML for you.

Is there a way I can get arbitrary JavaScript to work with Odoo's built-in payment system? Is there any other way to integrate Stripe with Odoo?

Answer (score 1):

I'm interested in this myself, yesterday someone posted this which looks to be a start towards what you are going for: [implementing stripe checkout issues qweb for acquirer button 84467](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/implementing-stripe-checkout-issues-qweb-for-acquirer-button-84467)

Presumably, the `t-att-` prefix and wrapping in a template might help but I'm not far enough along to know for sure.

The way PayPal works in this scenario is a redirect to PayPal with a callback URL.  It is sort of `apples` :: `oranges` to the way Stripe Checkout works.

If I were to hazard a guess, if the `t-att` eval + template worked you could wrap this in a module [with its own controller](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/addons/payment_adyen/controllers/main.py#L18) to perform the actual Stripe API transactions with the token it provides you if the card is valid.  Whether you use Stripe.JS or Stripe Checkout you still need to process the token server side.

If I ever figure it out, I'll post something here.

Comment: I should mention, the easiest payment module to start ripping out and replacing code, in my opinion, is Ogone.

Comment: Thanks for posting this. I am finding developing for Odoo to be quite painful as there isn't much quality documentation or an easy way to test my add-on without installing and running the whole thing.

Comment: Yes, agreed, I've had the same experience.  I am not sure how they can make it better though.  Dealing with intermodule dependencies is probably the worst part.

Comment: @dg123: did you ever figure this out?  I'm nearly done with my implementation after putting it on the back burner for awhile...

Comment: No, I never figured this out. The company I was working for at the time actually dumped Odoo...

Comment: @dg123: Ah, I see.  The documentation has improved quite a bit lately and once you wrap your head around QWeb and Odoo's ORM and MVC pattern it isn't that bad...

Answer (score 1):

I have a website with stripe and `checkout.js` working.

It's a bit different from other gateways, there is really just one return URL.

I decided to add the key to the `payment_acquirer` model, and most of the heavy lifting into the model which inherits `payment_transaction` model.

Anyway, here is the form and the include for the js:

```
<template id="stripe_acquirer_button">
  <form id='stripe_form' action='/payment/stripe/return' method="post" target="_self">
            <input id='stripe_order_amount' type="hidden"  name='amount' t-att-value="tx_values['stripe_order_amount']"/>
            <input id='stripe_publishable_key' type="hidden" t-att-value="tx_values['stripe_publishable_key']"/>
            <input id='stripe_reference' type="hidden" name='reference' t-att-value="tx_values['stripe_reference']"/>
    <input type='hidden' name='add_returndata' t-att-value="tx_values.get('add_returndata')"/>
            <input id='stripe_token' type="hidden" name='token' value="xxx"/>
  </form>
  <button id='customButton' type="submit" width="100px"
                t-att-class="submit_class">
                <img t-if="not submit_txt" src="/payment_stripe/static/src/img/stripe_icon.png"/>
                <span t-if="submit_txt"><t t-esc="submit_txt"/> <span class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"/></span>
      </button>

</template>

<template id="assets_common" name="global assets" inherit_id="web.assets_common">
  <xpath expr="." position="inside">
    <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>
        <script src="/payment_stripe/static/src/js/payment_stripe.js"></script>
  </xpath>
</template>
```